# Vue v-model changes parent data but doesn't change value prop in custom component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

someone to help me with this strange issue?

I have the following vue component:

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  p.alert.alert-info {{value}}
  button(@click="onChange") Change
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default {
    name: 'z-temp',
    props: {
      value: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    watch: {
      value(val) {
        console.log(val);
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onChange() {
        this.$emit('input', Random.id());
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

I want to use `v-model`, but when I use `<z-temp v-model="myDataField">`, the `myDataField` changes with success when I click in the `Change` button, but when I make the inverse and put some value in `myDataField`, like `myDataField: "foo"` the custom component gets `this.value` as `undefined` instead as `foo`.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It would be easier to guide you if you also shared the code where you use the z-temp component. Please add that, the broken version, to your question!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that myDataField is not reactive so the problem is in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify the problem, seems like it is working as it should, ie. the component does not seem to be the problem.

```js
zTemp = Vue.component('ztemp', {
 template: '#ztemp',
  props: {
    value: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      console.log(val);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      this.$emit('input', Math.random());
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
   zTemp
  },
  data: {
   myinput: '0.2'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{myinput}}<br/>
  <input v-model="myinput"/><br/>
  <ztemp v-model="myinput"/><br/>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="ztemp">
  <div>
    <p>{{value}}</p>
    <button @click="onChange">Change</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping, but I'm using `meteor` with `vue-meteor`, the problem was related to `vue-meteor`.

I changed the project structure to use separated Vue project in a `.client` folder and the problem gones. It was not a problema with component, but with vue-meteor package. Anyway, thank you guys.